# Spring FTP Client connection without TLS

Tags: java, xml, spring, ftp

I am stuggelin to create a ftp connection with the spring ftpSessionFactory.

In my project I am using the xml configuration for a ftp connection with TLS (it works):

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpsSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('file.transfer.server.host')}" />
    <property name="port" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('file.transfer.server.port')}" />
    <property name="username" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('file.transfer.server.user')}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('file.transfer.server.password')}" />
    <property name="clientMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="useClientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="TLS"/>
    <property name="trustManager" ref="trustManager"/>
    <property name="prot" value="P"/>
    <property name="needClientAuth" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionCreation" value="true"/>
    <property name="implicit" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Now I need a second connection, but without TLS (dont ask :D). For that I just replaced the fields in Java:

```
ftpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
ftpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
ftpSessionFactory.setUsername(username);
ftpSessionFactory.setPassword(password);
ftpSessionFactory.setProtocol(StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(protocol) ? protocol : null); // <-- null for no TLS
```

But that gives me this error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 500 AUTH: unknown command`.

Then I tried it the hard coded way (it works):

```
FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
f.connect(host);
f.login(username, password);
```

Now my question:
How can I modify the xml part (I guess with setter) so it works for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DefaultFtpSessionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/DefaultFtpSessionFactory.html) instead of `DefaultFtpsSessionFactory`.